# input tags with array

Tags: javascript

Recently I am doing a project in which I encountered a strange problem.

This is the program which previous programmer did MPAN:

```
<input name="mpan[]" id="mpan[]" value="" maxlength="2" size="2" >//this one to read
<input name="mpan[]" id="mpan[]" value="" maxlength="3" size="3">
<input name="mpan[]" id="mpan[]" value="" maxlength="3" size="3">
<input name="mpan[]" id="mpan[]" value="" maxlength="3" size="3">
<input name="mpan[]" id="mpan[]" value="" maxlength="3" size="3">//this one to read
```

I have to read it from a *javascript* what I did:

1) `document.getElementByName("mpan").value`  ==> not reading script does not work
2) `document.getElementByName("mpan[]").value` ==> reading first one
3) `document.getElementByName("mpan[0]").value` ==> script does not work
4) `document.getElementByName("mpan[3]").value` ==> script does not work
5) `document.getElementByName("mpan[]")[3].value` ==> not working

Can anybody tell me how to read this from a *javascript* program?

Comment: This is a total shot in the dark, but try `document.getElementByName("mpan")[3].value` note the `name`.

Comment: I've taken the time to format your code. You have to indent HTML with 4 spaces, or put it inside of backticks (`) if you want it to show.

Comment: Also, element IDs should *really* be unique.

Comment: AFAIK the id attribute don't work with arrays ("[]") as ALL id must be UNIQUE.

Answer (score 2):

In HTML the ID must be unique. So it is an error to use the same ID for more than one element.

Use different IDs for every element in the list. Supposedly you are parsing the POST (or GET) data with PHP, so that you can mantain the same `name` (mpan[]) with no problem.

Furthermore, the IDs can be composed only by certain characters; from W3C HTML Recommendation:

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a
>   letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed
>   by any number of letters, digits
>   ([0-9]), hyphens (”-”), underscores
>   (”_”), colons (”:”), and periods
>   (”.”).

Comment: Actually the W3C tells that neither the id nor the name can contain `[]`. But of course using the square brackets in the input names work, so I'm puzzled.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value

document.getElementsByTagName("input")[1].value

document.getElementsByTagName("input")[2].value

document.getElementsByTagName("input")[3].value
```

Answer (score 0):

One noticeable thing is `id` has to be *unique* to each element so `document.getElementById('mpan')` should not work.

The names of your fields can be same. So if you want to find elements based on names you can do:

```
document.getElementsByName('mpan[]')[0].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

An `id` is just a string, don't be fooled by the "[]" to assume this is an array, there's nothing to make the `id` property's value (or any other) have a meaning in JavaScript.

```
<a id="throw('don't click me bro');" href="about:blank">This should be OK too</a>
```

Other than that `id`s should be [unique in the document](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2).

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
  function ReadLines() {
            var x = document.getElementsByName("mpan[]");
            alert(x[3].value);
        }
```