# not able to form post data for passing in extjs

Tags: extjs

I have a strange problem with POST data, i have two conditions

I had four input boxes with name

```
<input name="a[]"><input name="a[]"><input name="a[]"><input name="a[]">
```

and data is posted by method "&a[]=12&a[]=9&a[]=12&a[]=43".

but when i am using extjs i am hanged if i do

```
store.load({params:{ 'a[]':12 ,'a[]':9 , 'a[]':12 , 'a[]':43      }});
```

this only a[]=43 reached to the post data and never to the another end ,

also if i do

```
store.load({params:{ a[]:12 ,a[]:9 , a[]:12 , a[]:43      }});
```

this is an error

so please help to clear my concept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this really works for the above problem Please solve that problem like this

```
store.load({params:{ 'a[0]':12 ,'a[1]':9 , 'a[2]':12 , 'a[3]':43      }});
```

Answer (score 0):

The name property corresponds to the HTTP field names for forms.  These need to be unique.  The system reads these in order.  Thus, only the last one a[]:43 is read in.  If you give each of the properties a unique name they will be read in...

e.g. (not tested)

```
<input name="a1"><input name="steaksauce"><input name="heinz"> <input name="57">

store.load({params:{ "a1" :"asdf", "steaksauce":"325", "heinz":"yummy", "57":"fitty"});
```

Please refer to [The HTTP Forms documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.3) for more information

Comment: hi Grunt , tag names can be repeated but id cannot be repeated Please try an example by your self on your system u will find whats true

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055931/input-tags-with-array
Please see this, 
also 
see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using input boxes with a format like this:

```
<input name="a[]"><input name="a[]"><input name="a[]"><input name="a[]">
```

Can you provide the exact code you are using?

Comment: this is my requirement as i have to deal with pre-built script